# List elements with multiple eventlisteners

Tags: jquery, events

Is there a way to list all elements that contain two or more events of the same kind?

I put a little example at JsBin:
http://jsbin.com/alafo3/edit

In this example I want a list that contains the `<p>` with ID="hallo2".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also access the `events` key of the attached data, e.g.

```
$('#hello2').data('events').click.length
```

returns `2`.

**Update:**

You could for example extend jQuery this way:

```
$.fn.hasMultipleEventHandlersFor = function(event) {
    return this.filter(function() {
        var events =  $(this).data('events');
        return events && events[event] && events[event].length > 1;
    });
};
```

And use it like:

```
$('p').hasMultipleEventHandlersFor('click');
```

which will select all elements that have multiple handlers for the click event.

Comment: Nice, also take care if checking for events on non DOM object (like window object) in jQuery 1.4.3+ see why in http://stackoverflow.com/a/4331226/352672

Answer (score 2):

You can loop over the `$.cache` object where events are stored, like this:

```
$.each($.cache, function(i, v) {
  if(v.events && v.events.click && v.events.click.length > 1) {
    alert($('[' + $.expando + '=' + i + ']').attr('id'));
  }
})​;
```

[Give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xEpSR/), or make it more generic for *any* event with multiple handlers, like this:

```
$.each($.cache, function(i, v) {
  $.each(v.events, function(j, u) {
    if(u.length > 1)
      alert($('[' + $.expando + '=' + i + ']').attr('id'));
  });
})​;
```

[You can try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xEpSR/1/),  Note that both of these approaches needs jQuery 1.4+, the `expando` property isn't exposed in 1.3.x.

---

If you want a jQuery collection referring to these elements, you can build it as you go, like this:

```
var elems = [];
$.each($.cache, function(i, v) {
  $.each(v.events, function(j, u) {
    if(u.length > 1)
      $.merge(elems, $('[' + $.expando + '=' + i + ']'));
  });
});
​$(elems).css('color', 'red');​​​​ //use it, $(DOMElementArray) overload here
```

[You can test that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/xEpSR/2/).

Comment: @downvoter - It helps to explain what you think is incorrect.  If you have knowledge that would improve the answer for future viewers it's best to share it.