# jQuery.data no longer works with window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I recently upgraded our project's jQuery file from `1.4.2` to `1.4.4` and it appears that as of `1.4.3` the way we have been using `jQuery.data` has stopped working.

We have this code:

```
var events = $(window).data('events');

if (events.scroll)
if (!events.scroll.include(handler))
  $(window).scroll(handler);
```

the purpose is to prevent this particular handler from being bound multiple times.

In `1.4.2`, this works fine. In `1.4.4`, `events` is undefined.

```
function handler() {
  //do something
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(handler);
  $('div#test').scroll(handler);

  $(window).data('events') -> undefined
  $('div#test').data('events') -> Object
});
```

What changed with this API? How should I list events for `window`?

---

I have changed the first line to this:

```
var events = $(window).data('__events__').events;
```

a bit messy-looking, but the ability to wire events to plain objects is compelling.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There was a change in jQuery 1.4.3+ for event types, to avoid object name collisions, for `window` (or any other plain object) use the key `"__events__"` instead, like this:

```
var events = $(window).data('__events__');
```

[The same `__events__` key is used for any objects that don't have a `.nodeType` property](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.4/src/event.js#L63) (which `window` doesn't, so it's treated like a plain object here).

---

To be clear that this was a conscious, intentional change, it's included in [the jQuery 1.4.3 release notes](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/10/16/jquery-143-released/):

> **JavaScript Objects**
>   A number of changes were made to when .data() is used on JavaScript objects (or, more accurately, anything that isn’t a DOM node). To start whenever you set data on a JavaScript object the data is set directly on the object – instead of going into the internal data object store. Additionally events that are attached to objects are put in a new `__events__` property that is actually a function. This was done to allow events to be attached directly to an object, be garbage collected when the object is collected, and not be serialized by a JSON serializer. These changes should make jQuery’s data and event systems much more useful on JavaScript objects.

Comment: Aha! Someone who actually has some idea of the real problem steps in xD +1

Answer (score 4):

[The basic API still seems to work.](http://jsfiddle.net/EGpmj/)

[However, it doesn't seem to work on the window.](http://jsfiddle.net/YEGbM/1/)

So, the API for accessing jQuery-assigned events hasn't really changed; it just no longer applies to the window. That doesn't exactly sound like an intentional decision, and the [1.4.3 -> 1.4.4 changelog](http://blog.jquery.com/2010/11/11/jquery-1-4-4-release-notes/) makes no mention of it.

Sounds like a bug, and it might have to do with the recent changes to `data` now being able to access HTML5 `data-` attributes. Consider [filing a ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/newticket) for it :/

Comment: It does not work with the `window` object. Check again. http://jsfiddle.net/dH4pz/

Comment: It's not a bug, the behavior is intentional in jQuery 1.4.3+